# Using voice recognition on nodejs webkit (nw) app fails

Tags: node.js, node-webkit, annyang

I have worked several days on implementing voice recognition in my nodejs webkit app and it failed yo work.

I have tried to write a local html file demo for it and it didnt work, so I used apache and putted the demo on a host and still didnt work.
Then I tried connecting to my localhost with https and it did work for my demo.
The problem is that I dont know how I can get my nodejs webkit app to run in a https enviorment.

Note that I have used annyang library for my demos and copied an example from their site that should work.

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Update 1:
As edwan rightfuly requested, here's a basic simple example to demonstrate my problem:

```
<script.         src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/annyang/2.0.0/annyang.min.js"></script>
<script>
if (annyang) {
// Let's define our first command.           First the text we expect, and then the.   function it should call
 var commands = {
  'hello': function() {
    alert("you said hello");
   }
 };

// Add our commands to annyang
annyang.addCommands(commands);

// Start listening. You can call.   this here, or attach this call to an.   event, button, etc.
 annyang.start();
 }
</script>
```

If you put this code in your nodejs webkit enviorment it wont work. Also in local chrome enviorment or on a host with http. Only in https it workedfor me

Comment: You have to give us some sample code at the very least. This sounds interesting, and you give a decent description of your challenge, but few people have the time to set up a project to test this on your behalve. Is it possible to give us some sample code that would be quick and easy to test and recreate your scenario?

Comment: Great, I'll take a look in a bit, work duties call first.

Comment: I haven't had any luck yet, it could be because I'm on a Mac, there seem to be lots of problems with Macs and this library.